# How to show links/pictures just for a special label with an if - else condition in blogger?

Tags: html, if-statement, blogger

I want to show for certain labels certain affiliate links in my blogspot blog. I have tried different varieties of the following code, but none worked. When I parse the code blogger shows all three affiliate links or none. My intention is that if I have the label "Familie/Family" it shows another affiliate link as if I have the label "Garten/Garden".

The code i've tried was:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;true&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name == "Familie"'>
<div style="clear:both; margin:10px 0;text-align:center">
<a Link 1
</a>
<p class='text_werbung'>*)Anzeige</p>
</div>
<b:elseif cond='data:label.name == "Garten"'>
<div style="clear:both; margin:10px 0;text-align:center">
<a Link 2
</a>
<p class='text_werbung'>*)Anzeige</p>
</div>
</b:else>
<b:if cond='data:label.name == "Food"'>
<div style="clear:both; margin:10px 0;text-align:center">
<a Link 3
</a>
<p class='text_werbung'>*)Anzeige</p>
</div>
</b:if>
</b:if>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
<b:include data='post' name='post' />
</b:if>
```

Maybe anyone can help me to solve that problem.

Thank you very much!
Greetings Kathrin

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```xml
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "Familie")'>
<!-- link 1 -->
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "Garten")'>
<!-- link 2 -->
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "Food")'>
<!-- link 3 -->
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.labels none (label => label.name in ["Garten","Familie","Food"])'>
<!-- link 4 -->
</b:if>
```

Comment: I have tried that code, but it shows me all links and not a specific one :( Why?

Comment: If I want to show a forth link, if the labels aren't Familie, Food and Garten, would this be correct: <b:if cond='data:post.labels none (label => label.name not in {"Garten","Familie","Food"}
)'>

Comment: @Kathrin You don't need "**not**", check the updated answer.

Comment: Glad it helped :)